# Sister i-joist for subfloor install?

Tags: bathroom, joists, subfloor

[image: drawing of hole / joists labeled]I am doing a small bathroom remodel that turned big...now replacing a 4' by 4' section of subfloor thanks to discovering surface mold on the subfloor (no rot).

The joists are 16" on center and lo and behold are I-Joists, except for one which is an i-joist + 2x (B on the drawing). I've cut the hole to expose 1/2 of the joists at either edge (A & D on the drawing). Before I saw these were i-joists, my plan was to sister to those (A & D) for extra stability for the new subfloor. How would you sister to an i-joist? Or since the area is relatively small, will I be okay just fastening into the existing i-joists?

When I get to it, the subfloor will be 3/4" marine grade ply to match existing subfloor + 1/4" Go Board or similar for small tile (max 4" to a side) installation.

This is my first time posting... I saw and read several posts about sistering to joists for bathroom remodels, but none that talked about I-joists. If I missed something, feel free to point me in the right direction! Thank you in advance ffor helping me figure this out!

Comment: If they are not sagging/cracked/rotted, would leave them be, unless you are putting a big hot tub over them.  If it is not broken, don't fix idea.  I joists usually quite stable and strong, especially over short distances.

Comment: Thanks! They are in great shape, I just wasn't sure if the new subfloor would need extra stability since it's now got those edges. I wish I was installing a hot tub! Just a normal acrylic tub, it weighs 100# but it does have extra soaking depth so holds more water than usual. With water and me in it, probably 650#

Comment: Oh also! What type of fasteners would you use for the new subfloor into the I-joists?

Comment: Screws be best, can also use construction adhesive with screws.

Comment: Surface mold and you ripped it out? Seems like scrubbing it with bleach to kill the mold would have been much more straight forward, easier and more cost effective. Oh well, subfloor under the bridge, as they say. I would suggest taking a close look at the joist that was sistered. There's a good chance that the sister is simply for supporting the edge of a 4x8 sheet of subfloor without cutting the plywood, but it's worth looking at the i-joist for damage that the sister was intended to repair.

Comment: Yeah I think I went a little overboard in retrospect but there wasn't really a way to confirm that it was just surface mold without cutting it up and I was getting paranoid! Sigh. Thanks for the tip on the already sistered I-joist! I'll re-check it. Do you agree with crip's post that I should be okay fastening to the exposed i-joist halves on the two edges of the holes without additional reinforcement there? Thank you so much!